# Can't pass unit testing for a simple math question

Tags: python, numpy, unit-testing

This is the code I scraped together and when unit testing it, I receive two errors shown below. The code works fine otherwise. How can I edit it to pass the test? I would greatly appreciate your help.

Also, if you know any resources which would help me learn to do it myself next time, please feel free to suggest one. Thank you very much in advance.

```
import numpy as np


def calculate(arr):
    if len(arr) != 9:
        raise ValueError('List must contain nine numbers.')
    else:
        arr = np.array(arr)
        new_arr = arr.reshape((3, 3))
        mean = {'mean': [np.mean(new_arr, 0).tolist(), np.mean(new_arr, 1).tolist(), np.mean(arr).tolist()]}
        variance = {'variance': [np.var(new_arr, 0).tolist(), np.var(new_arr, 1).tolist(), np.var(arr).tolist()]}
        standard_deviation = {
            'standard deviation': [np.std(new_arr, 0).tolist(), np.std(new_arr, 1).tolist(), np.std(arr).tolist()]}
        maxi = {'max': [np.max(new_arr, 0).tolist(), np.max(new_arr, 1).tolist(), np.max(arr).tolist()]}
        mini = {'min': [np.min(new_arr, 0).tolist(), np.min(new_arr, 1).tolist(), np.min(arr).tolist()]}
        summ = {'sum': [np.sum(new_arr, 0).tolist(), np.sum(new_arr, 1).tolist(), np.sum(arr).tolist()]}
        return print(mean), print(variance), print(standard_deviation), print(maxi), print(mini), print(summ)


calculate([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

### ERROR: test_calculate (test_module.UnitTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/runner/RectangularConsiderateInverse/test_module.py", line 10, in test_calculate
self.assertAlmostEqual(actual, expected, "Expected different output when calling 'calculate()' with '[2,6,2,8,4,0,1,5,7]'")

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 943, in assertAlmostEqual
diff = abs(first - second)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'dict'

### ERROR: test_calculate2 (test_module.UnitTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/runner/RectangularConsiderateInverse/test_module.py", line 15, in test_calculate2
self.assertAlmostEqual(actual, expected, "Expected different output when calling 'calculate()' with '[9,1,5,3,3,3,2,9,0]'")

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 943, in assertAlmostEqual
diff = abs(first - second)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'dict'

**The unit testing code:**

````
import unittest
import mean_var_std


# the test case
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_calculate(self):
        actual = mean_var_std.calculate([2,6,2,8,4,0,1,5,7])
        expected = {'mean': [[3.6666666666666665, 5.0, 3.0], [3.3333333333333335, 4.0, 4.333333333333333], 3.888888888888889], 'variance': [[9.555555555555557, 0.6666666666666666, 8.666666666666666], [3.555555555555556, 10.666666666666666, 6.222222222222221], 6.987654320987654], 'standard deviation': [[3.091206165165235, 0.816496580927726, 2.943920288775949], [1.8856180831641267, 3.265986323710904, 2.494438257849294], 2.6434171674156266], 'max': [[8, 6, 7], [6, 8, 7], 8], 'min': [[1, 4, 0], [2, 0, 1], 0], 'sum': [[11, 15, 9], [10, 12, 13], 35]}
        self.assertAlmostEqual(actual, expected, "Expected different output when calling 'calculate()' with '[2,6,2,8,4,0,1,5,7]'")

    def test_calculate2(self):
        actual = mean_var_std.calculate([9,1,5,3,3,3,2,9,0])
        expected = {'mean': [[4.666666666666667, 4.333333333333333, 2.6666666666666665], [5.0, 3.0, 3.6666666666666665], 3.888888888888889], 'variance': [[9.555555555555555, 11.555555555555557, 4.222222222222222], [10.666666666666666, 0.0, 14.888888888888891], 9.209876543209875], 'standard deviation': [[3.0912061651652345, 3.39934634239519, 2.0548046676563256], [3.265986323710904, 0.0, 3.8586123009300755], 3.0347778408328137], 'max': [[9, 9, 5], [9, 3, 9], 9], 'min': [[2, 1, 0], [1, 3, 0], 0], 'sum': [[14, 13, 8], [15, 9, 11], 35]}
        self.assertAlmostEqual(actual, expected, "Expected different output when calling 'calculate()' with '[9,1,5,3,3,3,2,9,0]'")
    
    def test_calculate_with_few_digits(self):
        self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "List must contain nine numbers.", mean_var_std.calculate, [2,6,2,8,4,0,1,])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main() ```
````

Comment: show the UT code please. Your code return a `tuple` of 6 `None` values. Those values are the result of the `print(..)`

Comment: @balderman I edited the original post with the UnitTest code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code (`return print(mean), print(variance), print(standard_deviation), print(maxi), print(mini), print(summ)` )

return a tuple with 6 None elements.

Your UT code is expecting to get a dict.

Modify the code and make `calculate` return the expected dict (`{'mean': ...`).